# Map generator for a text-based role-playing game

Tags: python, performance, beginner, role-playing-game

I am semi new to coding and have been following a tutorial on making a "text based RPG" on CodeClub.

Here is the full code:

```
#!/bin/python3

# Replace RPG starter project with this code when new instructions are live

def showInstructions():
  #print a main menu and the commands
  print('''
RPG Game
========

Get to the Garden with a key, a knife and a matchbox
But beware of the monsters!

Commands:
  go [direction]
  get [item]
''')

def showStatus():
  #print the player's current status
  print('---------------------------')
  print('You are in the ' + currentRoom)
  #print the current inventory
  print('Inventory : ' + str(inventory))
  #print an item if there is one
  if "item" in rooms[currentRoom]:
    print('You see a ' + rooms[currentRoom]['item'])
  print("---------------------------")

#an inventory, which is initially empty
inventory = []

#a dictionary linking a room to other rooms
rooms = {

            'Hall' : { 
                  'south' : 'Kitchen',
                  'east'  : 'Dining Room',
                  'item'  : 'key'
                },

            'Kitchen' : {
                  'north' : 'Hall',
                  'east'  : 'Living Room',
                  'item'  : 'knife'
                },
            'Dining Room' : {
                  'west'  : 'Hall',
                  'south' : 'Living Room',
                  'east'  : 'Garden',
                  'item'  : 'matchbox'
                },
            'Living Room' : {
                  'north' : 'Dining Room',
                  'west'  : 'Kitchen',
                  'item'  : 'monster'
                },
            'Garden' : {
                  'west'  : 'Dining Room'
            }

         }

# Displays a map of all the accesable rooms from the current room.
def room_map():

  # Makes sure that a variable defaults to an empty string...
  # ...if the current room doesnt link to another room in that direction.
  try:
    north = rooms[currentRoom]['north']
  except:
    north = ""
  try:
    south = rooms[currentRoom]['south']
  except:
    south = ""
  try:
    east = rooms[currentRoom]['east']
  except:
    east = ""
  try:
    west = rooms[currentRoom]['west']
  except:
    west = ""

  # Prints the map
  n = "N"
  s = "S"
  vert_line = "|"
  hzt_line = "-- W -- X -- E --"
  print(north.center(30))
  print("")
  print(vert_line.center(30))
  print(n.center(30))
  print(vert_line.center(30))
  print(west + hzt_line.center(30 - len(west) * 2) + east)
  print(vert_line.center(30))
  print(s.center(30))
  print(vert_line.center(30))
  print("")
  print(south.center(30))
  print("")

#start the player in the Hall
currentRoom = 'Hall'

showInstructions()

#loop forever
while True:
  room_map()
  showStatus()

  #get the player's next 'move'
  #.split() breaks it up into an list array
  #eg typing 'go east' would give the list:
  #['go','east']
  move = ''
  while move == '':  
    move = input('>')

  move = move.lower().split()

  #if they type 'go' first
  if move[0] == 'go':
    #check that they are allowed wherever they want to go
    if move[1] in rooms[currentRoom]:
      #set the current room to the new room
      currentRoom = rooms[currentRoom][move[1]]
    #there is no door (link) to the new room
    else:
        print('You can\'t go that way!')

  #if they type 'get' first
  if move[0] == 'get' :
    #if the room contains an item, and the item is the one they want to get
    if "item" in rooms[currentRoom] and move[1] in rooms[currentRoom]['item']:
      #add the item to their inventory
      inventory += [move[1]]
      #display a helpful message
      print(move[1] + ' got!')
      #delete the item from the room
      del rooms[currentRoom]['item']
    #otherwise, if the item isn't there to get
    else:
      #tell them they can't get it
      print('Can\'t get ' + move[1] + '!')
  # player loses if they enter a room with a monster
  if 'item' in rooms[currentRoom] and 'monster' in rooms[currentRoom]['item']:
    print('A monster has got you....GAME OVER!')
    break

  # player wins if they get to the garden with a key, a matchbox and a knife
  if currentRoom == 'Garden' and 'key' in inventory and 'matchbox' in inventory and 'knife' in inventory:
    print('You escaped the house... YOU WIN!')
    break
```

I have tried to implement my own map/compass to display the players current location in relationship to the accesable rooms.
My code works but is very repetitive and not very efficient.

I am interested in simplifying the `room_map()` function.

I will eventually go about creating a real map with rooms and walls that can be updated in terms of player location, enemies etc.

The map looks like this and updates when I go to another room:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since “Dining Room” (11 characters long) is west of the garden, you probably want

```
west.rjust(11) + hzt_line + east
```

for your room map.  (You’ll have to increase your centering values to accommodate the additional characters.)

---

Since `['item']` is often in a room dictionary, the player can type “go item”, moving to the “item” room, crashing the game.  You should validate the move directions.  One way: instead of move directions stored as keys of the room, store them in a `'exits'` dictionary in the room.

```
'Kitchen' : {
    'exits' : { 'north': 'Hall', 'east': 'Living Room'},
    ...
```

---

You can test for many similar conditions using `all(...)` and list comprehension.

```
if currentRoom == 'Garden'  and  all(item in inventory for item in ('key', 'matchbox', 'knife')):
    ...
```

But really you want `inventory` to be a `set`.  Then you can test:

```
if currentRoom == 'Garden'  and  inventory >= {'key', 'matchbox', 'knife'}:
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! The last line of code is much better than what I had

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/python3
```

This is rarely where Python lives. Typically you should instead write

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Your rooms dict shouldn't really be a dict. Dicts are good for serialization and web APIs, but in Python they're often abused. You should use a `namedtuple`, if not an actual class.

Here:

```
# Displays a map of all the accesable rooms from the current room.
def room_map():
```

The convention for function documentation is to use the following format:

```
def room_map():
"""
Displays a map of all the accessible rooms from the current room.
"""
```

When you do this:

```
try:
    north = rooms[currentRoom]['north']
except:
    north = ""
```

There are several problems. First, your except clause is way, way too broad. You probably want to catch `KeyError`. However, the saner thing to do is:

```
north = rooms.get(currentRoom, {}).get('north', '')
```

You also have a bunch of code in global scope. This should be reduced - you should move that code into one or more functions.

```
'You can\'t go that way!'
```

should simply be

```
"You can't go that way!"
```

Comment: Thank you! I somehow missed these replies, but I am very thankful for the response! I might just dive into that project again with your insight :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you borrowed code from [this page on usingpython.com](http://usingpython.com/python-rpg-game/) in order to make this because of the dictionary and the `move = input("").lower().split()`. No shame in that, it's a useful site. I use it too. Try instead of if item in room and if enemy in room, try if a enemy is in the room. So if a enemy is in the room, then it would display game over if a enemy is in the room, meaning you dont have to add extra items into a room

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This answer is a little in the brief side, which isn’t bad but could you expand it a little? Specifically you stated “_Try instead of if item in room and if enemy in room, try if a enemy is in the room._” can you explain to the OP what advantages this would have?

Comment: (The diction differs between [Axel Sorensen's qustion](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/207997) and the site/code linked: pleas use the terms (*monster*) from the question.)